# grunt uncss cannot seem to set the css path

Tags: gruntjs, uncss

I have setup a uncss grunt task.
my html files are in the 'public' folder
my css ares in 'public/css'.

I setup my grunt task like so:

```
uncss: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'faq.min.css' : ['public/faq.html']
            }
        }
    }
```

I get an error saying:

```
Fatal error: UnCSS: could not open /css
```

I do import my css like so in my html page:

```
    <link href="css/faq.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I've tried setting up htmlroot, csspath, but nothing seems to work.

if I set

```
csspath: 'css'
```

it adds an extra css to the path.

```
/homepage/public/css/css/faq.min.css
```

anyone can help?